# Date Arithmetic in Access 2016 Web Application

Tags: ms-access, web

I am trying to write a simple expression in Access 2016 web.   I want to do this:  `DateAdd(Day,7,[txtStartDate])` but I keep getting an error message that Access cannot interpret this expression.

Does anyone know how to do this in Access 2016 web forms?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your syntax is wrong. To add 7 days to `[txtStartDate]`, you can use one of the following:

```
DateAdd("d", 7, [txtStartDate])
```

OR

```
[txtStartDate] + 7
```

OR

```
DateAdd("w", 1, [txtStartDate])
```

(7 days is one week)

Comment: Thank you.   Of your three suggestions, the only one that worked for me was [txtStartDate] + 7  - so that is what I will use.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, think about accepting it. Read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how accepting an answer works, and what the advantages are.